# Error during iteration on dataframe rows

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to define location given the latitude and longitude, that I have in the dataframe:

```
    lat        long
  40.712784   -74.005941
  55.755826   37.617300
  41.902783   12.496366
```

I'm using geopy library, and I'd like store the retrieving locations in new third column of existing dataframe. to have smth like:

```
    lat        long        location 
  40.712784   -74.005941   New-York
  55.755826   37.617300    Moscow
  41.902783   12.496366    Rome
```

The code that I execute is :

```
def take_location():
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    df['location']=''
    for row, index in df.iterrows():
        location= geolocator.reverse("%f, %f" % (row['lat'], row['long']))
        row['location']=location.address
    return df
```

Problem occurs on this line:
 `----> 6         location= geolocator.reverse("%f, %f" % (row['lat'], row['long']))` with following 
 `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` 
  I suppose there could be something wrong with arguments, and extracting values from row cells

Comment: Please avoid posting again questions already deleted without improving them with reproducible code.

Comment: @Fabio, could you explain, please, where my code is not reproducible?

Comment: just because the dataframe doesn't contain any information to correctly reproduce and run your function; the '....' are not 'lat', 'long' coordinates.

Comment: @Fabio, thank you for explanation, it was not very clear what part of code I should improve, now I get it

Comment: You're welcome, I've upvoted now your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.iterrows()` gives values in order - `(index, row)` - but you are assuming it to be coming in order `(row,index)` , which is wrong, and hence you are getting the issue. You should use -

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    location= geolocator.reverse("%f, %f" % (row['lat'], row['long']))
    row['location']=location.address
```